# Php array wrong output when try to add in html tag

Tags: php, arrays

I wander why my code produce a wrong output.

```
$array = require 'http://vilavaleaprahovei.ro/kimea/allMarks.php';
$output = array_keys($array);
$option = '';
foreach ($output as $val) {
    $option .= "<option>$val</option>";
}
print_r($option);
```

Expected result is:

```
<option>ALCAR STAHLRAD</option>
<option>ENZO</option>
<option>DEZENT</option>
...........
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: what are you getting after printing $array.

Comment: My result is here: http://vilavaleaprahovei.ro/kimea/mark.php

Comment: `require` doesn't work in the way it looks like you think it does

Comment: what does the `print_r($output);` give?

Comment: instead of require you should do following: `$array = file_get_contents('http://vilavaleaprahovei.ro/kimea/allMarks.php');
$array = unserialize($array);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this I hope it will works :

```
$data = array('ALCAR STAHLRAD' => array('diametru' => array(0 => 15, 6 => 16, 9 => 14, 14 => 13, 20 => 17, 468 => 20,), 'latime' => array(0 => 6, 9 => 5, 10 => 4, 27 => 7, 501 => 3,), 'pcd' => array(0 => 15, 6 => 16, 9 => 14, 14 => 13, 20 => 17, 468 => 20,), 'pcd1' => array(0 => 15, 6 => 16, 9 => 14, 14 => 13, 20 => 17, 468 => 20,), 'et' => array(0 => 15, 6 => 16, 9 => 14, 14 => 13, 20 => 17, 468 => 20,), 'cb' => array(0 => 15, 6 => 16, 9 => 14, 14 => 13, 20 => 17, 468 => 20,),), 'ENZO' => array('diametru' => array(0 => 16, 2 => 17, 3 => 15, 10 => 14, 14 => 18,), 'latime' => array(0 => 6, 1 => 7, 10 => 5, 35 => 8,), 'pcd' => array(0 => 16, 2 => 17, 3 => 15, 10 => 14, 14 => 18,), 'pcd1' => array(0 => 16, 2 => 17, 3 => 15, 10 => 14, 14 => 18,), 'et' => array(0 => 16, 2 => 17, 3 => 15, 10 => 14, 14 => 18,), 'cb' => array(0 => 16, 2 => 17, 3 => 15, 10 => 14, 14 => 18,),), 'DEZENT' => array('diametru' => array(0 => 17, 1 => 16, 6 => 15, 24 => 18, 46 => 14, 80 => 19, 159 => 20,), 'latime' => array(0 => 7, 6 => 6, 20 => 8, 63 => 5, 120 => 4, 159 => 9,), 'pcd' => array(0 => 17, 1 => 16, 6 => 15, 24 => 18, 46 => 14, 80 => 19, 159 => 20,), 'pcd1' => array(0 => 17, 1 => 16, 6 => 15, 24 => 18, 46 => 14, 80 => 19, 159 => 20,), 'et' => array(0 => 17, 1 => 16, 6 => 15, 24 => 18, 46 => 14, 80 => 19, 159 => 20,), 'cb' => array(0 => 17, 1 => 16, 6 => 15, 24 => 18, 46 => 14, 80 => 19, 159 => 20,),), 'DOTZ' => array('diametru' => array(0 => 17, 1 => 15, 3 => 18, 5 => 16, 6 => 19, 65 => 20,), 'latime' => array(0 => 7, 1 => 6, 2 => 8, 71 => 9,), 'pcd' => array(0 => 17, 1 => 15, 3 => 18, 5 => 16, 6 => 19, 65 => 20,), 'pcd1' => array(0 => 17, 1 => 15, 3 => 18, 5 => 16, 6 => 19, 65 => 20,), 'et' => array(0 => 17, 1 => 15, 3 => 18, 5 => 16, 6 => 19, 65 => 20,), 'cb' => array(0 => 17, 1 => 15, 3 => 18, 5 => 16, 6 => 19, 65 => 20,),), 'AEZ' => array('diametru' => array(0 => 16, 1 => 17, 5 => 18, 10 => 19, 28 => 20, 106 => 21, 157 => 22,), 'latime' => array(0 => 7, 1 => 8, 16 => 9, 105 => 6, 106 => 11, 114 => 10,), 'pcd' => array(0 => 16, 1 => 17, 5 => 18, 10 => 19, 28 => 20, 106 => 21, 157 => 22,), 'pcd1' => array(0 => 16, 1 => 17, 5 => 18, 10 => 19, 28 => 20, 106 => 21, 157 => 22,), 'et' => array(0 => 16, 1 => 17, 5 => 18, 10 => 19, 28 => 20, 106 => 21, 157 => 22,), 'cb' => array(0 => 16, 1 => 17, 5 => 18, 10 => 19, 28 => 20, 106 => 21, 157 => 22,),),);
// Above array is your data
$option = '';
foreach ($data as $key => $val) {
    $option .= "<option>$key</option>";
}
print_r(htmlentities($option));
```

Answer (score 2):

ensure you have `allow_url_include = On` in your `php.ini`

if `allMarks.php` is a php file where you declare and return an array you should open the php script tag `<?php` first and use the `return` keyword as follow:

```
<?php
return array (
  'ALCAR STAHLRAD' => 
  array ( ...
```

Answer (score -1):

the problem you are facing is that you want to print html without rendering it on html so you should be using

```
 foreach ($output as $val) {
    $option .= "&lt;option&gt;$val&lt;/option&gt; </br>";
}
```

instead of

```
foreach ($output as $val) {
    $option .= "<option>$val</option>";
}
```

Comment: Now on server is: $array = require 'http://vilavaleaprahovei.ro/kimea/allMarks.php';
$output = array_keys($array);
$option = '';
foreach ($output as $val) {
    $option .= "&lt;option&amp;$val&lt;/option&amp$val&lt;/br&amp;";
}
print_r($option);         But result is the same: http://vilavaleaprahovei.ro/kimea/mark.php

Comment: can you print echo "<pre>"; print_r($array); instead of print_r($option);